# Why is a Windows 11 machine only able to connect to router on LAN?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-11, windows-11-v22h2, windows-11-v23h2

- Tested with Windows firewall off (yes, all profiles)
- Tested with private profile on (but with IP exceptions) as this is profile ethernet adapter is set to.
- No 3rd party AV or firewall
- Same subnet as everything else on the network
- No VLANs in use
- Router is an ASUS RT-AC5300 recently factory reset. As far as I know, no route tables are in use/configured. No restrictions explicitly configured for any machine at the router level.
- All other machines (wired or wireless) on the network can communicate with each other just fine(access shares, printers, etc.), but the problem machine does not even when switching between wireless and wired connection.
- Windows Network Troubleshooter only indicates no connection to the target machine(and that's any machine on the network)
- Tried a separate profile on the same machine to check for corrupted account.
- Recent Windows update from 22h2 to 23h2 did not resolve the issue.

All connections fail at the localhost level. Tracert times out infinitely, ping fails, ssh fails, etc. All other hosts cannot ping the Windows 11 machine either.

Connections to web apps on the same network all fail as well.

I do have other Windows 11 machines on the same network, but they can connect to network resources just fine. Biggest difference between this machine and others is that it is an alienware machine that I picked up on sale.

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek Gaming 2.5GbE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7cab:f838:81f7:20a1%15(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.140(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.192
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, November 17, 2023 11:10:08 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, November 18, 2023 11:23:33 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.129
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.129
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 114071269
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2B-DC-B1-B5-CC-96-E5-0F-D1-9B
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.129
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I've begun to suspect the issue is Windows itself.

---

**Edit**: After reset I did make the change to the router for a `/26`, but issue existed on the original `/24` as well.

This is the newest machine on the network, and I originally believed this to be a Window 11 issue, but my spouse's Windows 10 machine, after being upgraded to Windows 11, works just fine.

So my question then is, if by default and even after any changes, all other machines can talk to each other, why is this one unable to do so?

Comment: I am a little confused by what your actual problem is, can you elaborate, by editing your question?

Comment: Rather strange that on the 192.168.1.x network, you have a netmask of /26, rather than the more normal /24, especially after a factory reset. What's the betting that the other systems are on /24 & your Win11 system cannot see them & your router drops the packets as is sees them as part of the same network.

Comment: Please note that the question Title is not for the question itself but is for a title, something that gives a very brief summary or context. Put a clear question in the body of your post.